# jQuery - Get image title

Tags: jquery, attr

Really simple one but I can't work it out.

How do I get the title of the image in the code below from clicking the surrounding `<a>`

```
$(this,'img').attr('title');
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="01.jpg"><img src="01_th.jpg" title="image_1" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="02.jpg"><img src="02_th.jpg" title="image_2" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="03.jpg"><img src="03_th.jpg" title="image_3" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var img_href = $(this).attr('href');
        var img_title = $(this,'img').attr('title');
        alert(img_title); //undefined.
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `$('img', this)` instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to put the context to find within as the second argument:

```
$('img', this).attr('title');
```

Comment: UNRELATED - can you provide the documentation for using $('element',this)...would like to read up!

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, i did not know this selector before.

Comment: @pmandell sorry it's *a little* late... https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 3):

You can get img title like this

```
$(this).find('img').attr('title');
```